# WPF Nested User Control

Tags: wpf, user-controls

I have build a WPF User Control which contains a ComboBox with a custom popup window which contains a User Control the inner control (the one in the popup) has some properties that I want to expose in the main user control so the host page can read and write to the inner control.

I am having trouble doing this is there something I am doing wrong or is what I am doing ill advised ?

Regards Christian Andersen

Comment: your user control should be able to expose those properties and pass them to the inner control ... mind showing some code?

Comment: What type of properties you want to expose? You can take help of dependency properties. Please share your code if you can.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the trouble you're having? It's difficult to help when you haven't explained how what you've tried isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

you can try exposing it using this

```
public static IEnumerable<T> FindVisualChildren<T>(this DependencyObject depObj) where T : DependencyObject
        {
            if (depObj == null) yield break;
            for (var i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
            {
                var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);
                var children = child as T;
                if (children != null)
                {
                    yield return children;
                }

                foreach (T childOfChild in FindVisualChildren<T>(child))
                {
                    yield return childOfChild;
                }
            }
        }
```

How I use it

```
var uc = (TabItem)sender;

            foreach (TextBlock textBlock in uc.FindVisualChildren<TextBlock>())
            {
                textBlock.Foreground = Brushes.WhiteSmoke;
            }
```